# getting error in python requests.get() method

Tags: python, request

```
import string
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

song_name = input('enter song name : ')
url = 'https://search.azlyrics.com/search.php?q='  + (string.capwords(song_name)).replace(' ', '+')
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.find_all('a'):
    href = a.get('href')
    if href.find('https') != -1:
        if href.find('lyrics/') != -1:
            print(href)
            res = requests.get(href)
            break
```

When i pass argument href into `requests.get(href)` it throws an error. while when i'm passing an constant string e.g., `res = requests.get('https://google.co.in')` it doesn't not throw any error.

I checked type of both variable is same

```
print(type(href))
<class 'str'>

print(type('https://google.co.in'))
<class 'str'>
```

Both are of same type then why i'm getting an error.

**input:**
*enter song name : god's plan*

Comment: i'm using python3.5

Comment: What is the error message that is being displayed?

Comment: Also, note that `soup.find_all('a')` is gathering *every* link on the site, which will probably include absolute paths for routing, which will not work with `requests.get` as no sitename is provided.

Comment: @Ajax1234 Thanx, i found the reason why i'm getting an error.

Comment: The below answer from @"touch my boom boom" is correct

Comment: @TylerCowan i solved this problem without appending http, https or www in beginning of base url.

Answer (score 0):

Your `href` is probably not a fully qualified URL.

You can check to see if your `href` begins with "http" or "www".

If it doesn't, then it's probably either of the form `#foo` or `foo/bar.html`, in which case you can simply append it to the end of the current pages' URL

Comment: Helps someone on StackOverflow *(God's Plan starts playing)*

Comment: <a class="btn btn-share" href="?q=%22god%27s+Plan%22&amp;w=songs&amp;p=1">More Song Results</a> is in your a list and when I print href above the if statements is makes it to this before erroring

Comment: you have to account for this in your logic and append to a base url